# Bootstrap: sticky footer or affix?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sticky-footer, affix

i tried to add an element to my page, which should stay on the bottom of the page until i scroll over it.

I'm using twitter bootstrap as css an js framework, so i tried to do it with the affix class.
But the element always stays in it's position and shows no function when i scroll over it.

Here is en example of what i want to do: http://www.brightpearl.com/features/shipping-management-software

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="affix" data-spy="affix-bottom" data-offset-top="200" data-offset-bottom="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Did an inspect element, and this is the css on the stick contaner...

```
.sticky-wrapper.stuck {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

pretty straight forward!

Comment: sorry, but this doesn't work for me to get the result i want :(

Comment: Why knock my reputation with a negative mark? Be more specific about what you want to accomplish and include your surrounding code if you want a specific solution. You stated that you wanted to replicate the sticky box at the bottom of the demo page you linked to. I simply answered with what they are doing. Do a "view source" and "inspect element" with your browser and replicate it. Otherwise we need to see more than one line of code to help you.

Comment: @SandraWillford This is not the answer to the question. I think that Simon was quite clear about the result he wanted to get.